# NoSuchElementException in while loop search

Tags: java

Hi here is some part of my code, when I tried to run this program it always throws a java.util.NoSuchElementException. In line String a = sub.next();. Could some please tell me how to fix that problem?

```
while(s.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = s.nextLine();
    Scanner sub = new Scanner(line);
    String a = sub.next();
    if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
    {
        replyMessage = line;
        break;
    }
    else if(word.equals(" ") || word.isEmpty())
    {
        replyMessage = "please give a word!";                   
    }
    else
    {
        replyMessage = "Can not find this word";                
    }
}
```

Comment: If `line` is empty, your `sub.next()` throws the mentioned exception, as there is no token in the buffer to be read....

Comment: @Nick I edited my previous answer, the first one was wrong

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to help if we could see how s is being populated.

```
 if(word.equals(" ") || word.isEmpty())
```

is logically equivalent to

```
if(word.trim().isEmpty())
```

and is simpler to type and understand.

EDIT

BTW you are looking at only the first element in each line.  You would need a nested loop to look through each element in the line which should take care of the element not found issue too.

```
while(s.hasNextLine())
{
String line = s.nextLine();
Scanner sub = new Scanner(line);

while(sub.hasNext())
{
String a = sub.next();
if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
{
    replyMessage = line;
    break;
}
else if(word.equals(" ") || word.isEmpty())
{
    replyMessage = "please give a word!";                   
}
else
{
    replyMessage = "Can not find this word";                
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I followed your suggestion and solved this problem. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the following code

```
String line = s.nextLine();
Scanner sub = new Scanner(line);
String a = sub.next();
```

You need to check whether sub has a next element, much like you did for s

add an if statement resembling this

```
if(sub.hasNext()){
    String a = sub.next();
```

Also you need to do something incase it doesn't, as your current program does not have a next line